# Minecraft server running, port open in nmap, but connection refused from outside the LAN

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have a Minecraft Server running on a computer of my LAN. It's the actual minecraft_server.jar, not a shared single player world, and I can connect to it from other devices on the LAN. I opened its port in the firewall and set up port forwarding so that it's accessible from the outside.

However, from outside the LAN, I get "connection refused". Online scanners (like [this one](https://pentest-tools.com/network-vulnerability-scanning/tcp-port-scanner-online-nmap)) say that the Minecraft Server port is open and can even detect the version of Minecraft, so the port seems to be forwarded correctly (I set it up in the router's settings), so I really don't understand how the connection can be refused.

The exact message I get is "Connection refused : no further information".

The server's `server.properties` file is the default one, with juste the difficulty changed to 2.

What can cause this "Connection refused" message ?

Comment: To clarify, you are trying to run a Minecraft Server on your computer? Then have another computer connect to yours to make a LAN-Server?

Comment: That's right. The LAN works, but I'm trying to open the server to the outside as well, to let a friend play from home.

Comment: Looking at your answer, my comment wasn't clear : when I say "the LAN works", it means that other devices on the LAN can connect to the server, not that I used the "share with LAN" option on a single player world. I'm running an actual `minecraft_server.1.11.2.jar`.

Comment: is your friend(Outside LAN ) trying to connect using your external IP address?

Comment: Yes. That's also the address I gave to the online scanner which saw the open port.

Answer (score 1):

Your question offers good informations, you should make some more tests:

1. you said the portscanner shows your port as open, but you should make sure that realy minecraft is running on that port. Maybe your Router has any service on the same port that "blocks" your minecraft. So try to change your server (and your port forwarding) to another port. Then check if the port is "offline" when you are NOT running your server, and becomes open, wenn you start your mc-server
2. check if you have a local firewall running on your compuser (sometimes LAN Firewall rules are different than rules for internet an public networks). Try to temporäry disable the firewall and check if you can connect. If yes, try to open the port for Minecraft in your local server.

Than another problem I know could be, if your provider uses IPv6.
Because there are multiple ways of IPv6, some providers use "Dual-Stack-Lite" and that would not work if you like to open server ports for games ect.

And IPv6 is even a more complex topic, because each computer behind your router will have an own IPv6 adress, wich is not identical to your router, so the best way is to use IPv4 for your server.

The most easy way is to call your Provider and request if they can offer IPv4 AND IPv6 in act run both paralell
Than you should use the IPv4 to connect to your Server.

Answer (score -3):

**Before-hand Note:** This answer works on the assumption that the Questioner was asking about LAN Servers on their computer - misconceptions happen...

## That will not work, Sorry.

That's practically impossible. Sorry. For why: LANs, or un-abbreviated as LOCAL Area Network, only connect with clients that are connected to the same Router (wifi router).

But if clients from across the world want to connect to your server, you'll need to set-up a **dedicated server** on your computer, or from a Server Provider (internet search).
If you want a Free, Temporary Alternative, you can use **Minecraft Realms** to take control of one of Mojangs personal servers for a set amount of time. And what's more: it's private and secure - *only you have the IP to it*.

## In short...

Set-up a **Dedicated Server** on Your Computer: [Minecraft Server Set-up](https://minecraft.net/en-us/download/server) or [Dedicated Server Google-search](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=minecraft+dedicated+server).

Create a **Local Area Network** Server, based on your computer, with you and your friend(s) connected to the same wifi-network (different PCs).

Set-up a **Minecraft Realm** on a different Private IP: [Minecraft Realms](https://minecraft.net/en-us/realms/pc/).

You're Welcome! :smiley-face:

Comment: What you call a "dedicated server" is what's currently running on my computer. That's what I call a "Minecraft Server". It's accessible from the LAN *and* from outside the LAN as the online nmap scans show. My friend could connect from home before, but I changed router and now I get this error.

Comment: I wrote this before knowing that you had a Client-based-Server.
Anyway: is your antivirus and or security measures (firewall and such) blocking your friend? Or is your specified IP address different to the one you provided them? (To check your IP, type in Google "What's my IP", or in your Command Console [or similar] ipconfig).

Comment: As I wrote I have allowed the Minecraft server to listen in the firewall, both Windows's and the router's, and I did it right as nmap sees the port open from the outside. The server PC did have an antivirus (Avira) but I don't see why it would be forcing the server to refuse incoming connections, especially given that it accepts them from the LAN. The IP is correct, both because I checked it 20 times with those "what's my IP" sites and because the scans found Minecraft listening on it, as expected. Really, I don't have any clue.

Comment: I'm really not sure what to say now... perhaps your IPv4 or IPv6 addresses are mixed-up. I'm not sure - it always seems to revolve around the IP-type. If that doesn't work, there's nothing else that I can offer you. Try going to the Mojang site for help on your agendas.

Comment: Yes, it seems that the server is reachable but refusing the connections from the outside. Really weird. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hamachi for LAN?